# Implementing skvideo.io.FFmpegReader in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skvideo
skvideo.setFFmpegPath("C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/site-packages/skvideo/io")
import skvideo.io
input_parameters ={}
output_parameters ={}
reader=skvideo.io.FFmpegReader("Cool_Kids.mp4",inputdict=input_parameters,outputdict=output_parameters)
num_frames,height,width,num_channels =reader.getShape()
print(num_frames, height, width, num_channels)
```

For analyzing Cool_Kids.mp4 video using skvideo library, before I would use

```
skvideo.setFFmpegPath("C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/site-packages/skvideo/io")
```

I was getting following error:

> AssertionError: Cannot find installation of real FFmpeg (which comes with ffprobe).

Then after researching a bit I found this setFFmpegPath command, but got the same error. What part am I missing? There is this link
[Cannot find installation of real FFmpeg (which comes with ffprobe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684772/cannot-find-installation-of-real-ffmpeg-which-comes-with-ffprobe/53685319), but I can't do more. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install FFmpeg command line tool.

It looks like have to install FFmpeg in your system outside of Python (I can't find a way to download ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe using `pip install` command).

[Note: Installing FFmpeg in Windows, is different from the way described in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684772/cannot-find-installation-of-real-ffmpeg-which-comes-with-ffprobe/53685319)].

You may also take a look at my answer to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-why).

---

Recommended solution:

- Download FFmpeg (include FFprobe) executable for Windows (download the statically linked version).
- Place ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe in the same folder.
  For example at: `c:/FFmpeg/bin`
- Set `setFFmpegPath` to the above folder:

  ```
   import skvideo
   skvideo.setFFmpegPath("C:/FFmpeg/bin")
   import skvideo.io
   ...
  ```

---

Note:
You may choose to place ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe in the folder:
`C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/lib/site-packages/skvideo/io`.